# How to close my jasperReport properly when it is in a Jdialog?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I create a Jdialog modallike this:

```
public class xxx extends javax.swing.JDialog {

public xxx(Object... parameters, boolean modal){
    super(parameters[0],modal);
    initComponents();
    //more code
}
private void btnPrintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    report();
} 

private void report(){
 String url = "C:\\ubication";

    CONEXIONBD cc = new CONEXIONBD();
    Connection cn = null;
    try {
        cn = cc.getConexion();
        JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(url);
        Map parametro = new HashMap();
        parametro.put("IDFACTURA", ptoVentas.ultimoID());
        parametro.put("TITULO", ptoVentas.leeNumFacturaParaDocReport(true));
        parametro.put("TIPODOC", ptoVentas.leeNumFacturaParaDocReport(false));

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,parametro, cn);

        JasperViewer jviewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, true);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this);//the owner
        dialog.setContentPane(jviewer.getContentPane());
        dialog.setSize(jviewer.getSize());
        dialog.setTitle("Ticket");
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winevt) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });            
        dialog.setVisible(true);

       }
```

This create a report into the JDialog, but when i closed the report and the JDialog window, in background still remains running the application, someone have any clues?

Comment: Can you create and post in your question a valid [mcve]  that we can test and verify your assertion? You can substitute thread-sleeps for the long-running code.

Comment: Where do you close the connection?

Comment: One issue that I *think* that I see is that your code does not appear to be handling Swing threading correctly as it appears to be running long-running code on the Swing event thread. If so, this can cause problems.

Comment: Well. Good eyes, @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas in the finally sentence of the try-catch, i close the connection, but i dont write that part i dont think it was important

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you explain more of this topic?

Comment: I hope by "the final sentence" you mean "in the finally clause of the try-catch-finally block"....